# Disable welcome email at first login

Tags: email, transactional-mail, registry

I've been trying to disable the welcome email for users who login to my Magento webshop for the first time. After some debugging and back-end configuration changes I couldn't quite figure out how to do this.

The important thing I don't want to happen is that the user wont receive the confirmation email with his username and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to disable the new account email, if that is the case you can try following:

Edit

> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Sales/Order/Create.php

and just comment the following

```
/*if (! $quote->getCustomer()->getId() || ! $quote->getCustomer()->isInStore($this->getSession()->getStore())) {
            $quote->getCustomer()->sendNewAccountEmail('registered', '', $quote->getStoreId());
        }*/
```

Then this:

```
//$this->_customer->sendNewAccountEmail();
```

Lastly:

```
//$customer->sendNewAccountEmail();
```

Hopefully it helps

Comment: Hi user6451, I figured it out myself after a couple of hours researching and debugging. I forgot to answer my own post and there by I now checked your answer as the correct one. Thanks for your time!

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: There are better solutions than editing the Core. Also this solution would only cover the email being sent when the account is created when placing an order from the admin not if the customer registers themselves through the frontend.

Answer (score 4):

You can rewrite the method `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::sendNewAccountEmail` and just make it return something without any other actions.

Comment: I've seen the method but wasn't sure if this also included the confirmation email with the two user credentials. If you tell me that's not the case here... I will rewrite it and thank you for your help.

Comment: I can tell you for sure that the method is used to send the e-mail to the customers when they create an account.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to prevent. The only thing I want to disable is the e-mail which get send after the customer log's into his account for the **first** time.

Comment: The customer does not get an email when logging in (as far as I know). Only for registering, and confirming his account (if the option is enabled)

Comment: I totally agree with you and I found it strange because it my first Magento shop where I get it. I've disabled the confirmation and tried it with multiple time delays between registration and logging in. But every time I end up with an e-mail right after I log for the first time. I want to add that I'm talking about Magento version 1.5.1.0.

Comment: Does anyone have a option how to solve this problem? A customer of mine is waiting for some results so I really would be thankful if anyone could help me out here.

Answer (score 3):

**Copy:** *app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php*

**TO:** *app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php*

In the function "**sendNewAccountEmail**" (around **line 561**), *comment out the last 2 lines* that perform the actual sending:

```
public function sendNewAccountEmail($type = 'registered', $backUrl = '', $storeId = '0')
{


$types = array(
'registered' => self::XML_PATH_REGISTER_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, // welcome email, when confirmation is disabled


'confirmed' => self::XML_PATH_CONFIRMED_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, // welcome email, when confirmation is enabled


'confirmation' => self::XML_PATH_CONFIRM_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, // email with confirmation link
);


if (!isset($types[$type])) {


Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('customer')->__('Wrong transactional account email type'));
}

if (!$storeId) {
$storeId = $this->_getWebsiteStoreId($this->getSendemailStoreId());


}


**// $this->_sendEmailTemplate($types[$type], self::XML_PATH_REGISTER_EMAIL_IDENTITY,**


**// array('customer' => $this, 'back_url' => $backUrl), $storeId);**


return $this;
}
```